# VBA - Hide a Form tab depending on the value of a field

Tags: ms-access, vba

pretty simple question here in scope.

**Question:**
Wondering If I would be able to hide the tabs of a form based off the values of a table's fields.

I have been reading the 2019 Access Bible and so far it is still unclear to me how I would write the VBA module to constantly be running. Im asking the question a little early in my attempts, but hoping I can ask this well enough to get a head start.

I dont quite understand the execution model of VBA for access yet. I have prior expierence coding but this will be my 1st time in access. Just looking for a little help on how to write the function scope. You see below that I think it should be "Main" something, as I want it to run whenever in form view. Like **I know how to write Private sub functions to respond to a button click. But not for a function that just runs in the background of the form.**

I was thinking something along the line of this below.

```
Main function()
If Me.FieldProcess_Water = "1" Then
Me.TabProcess_Water.Visible = True
Else
Me.TabProcess_Water.Visible  = False
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! This is a Visual Basic issue and has nothing to do with databases - please ask this question on StackOverflow! You'll be more than welcome back when  you have a question or questions about databases! Best...

Comment: ^I did not realize! Im sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good. The point is: when to execute?
In this case there are two events that should trigger the code: the Form_Current event for the form (showing a record) and the After_update event for the FieldProcess_Water control.

Comment: This got me going in the right direction. Gave me the awareness that I needed to dig into the documentation more. Thank you sir.